# What is the build number of Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

What is the build number of Windows 8.1? I don't know what is the build number of Windows 8.1.
I'm using Windows **8** Pro.

UPDATE: I found out that it is build 9600.

I can't answer my question as of the time of the writing.

Comment: I think it's `.1` of the `8th` variety. What's the question? How do you find the build number of your current OS?

Comment: @Raystafarian I found Windows 8's build number in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion. It's 9200. My Windows 8 can't update to Windows Store so I can't find Win8.1's. I need it for something important.

Comment: What are you trying to determine once you know the build number?  Unless you have installed the Windows 8.1 Update 1 or a year ago updated to Windows 8.1 using pre-release files you have the correct build number.

Comment: Nevermind. I found out that it's 9600.

Answer (score 2):

To see your current version, run `winver.exe`.

Microsoft does versioning as `[Major].[minor].[build]` (it was `[Major].[minor].[release].[build]` eons ago).
This means:

- **major** - "new os" or "new office" or similar
- **minor** - slight changes within the major release, but 'bigger' changes than e.g. a patch or something
- **build** - the source code was built this many times. It is a high number as one has to build the code (and release for testing) several times to see if it builds at all, works as intended, etc. Also a must have for [Black Box Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing).

Versioning is needed to track changes, defect fixes, etc.

Comment: I meant like this: 1.2.????, need to know the 4-digit thing.

Comment: I use Windows 8 and Win8 and Win8.1's build numbers are different (I think).

Comment: I found out that it's 9600.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 has the version 6.2.9200

Windows 8.1 has the version 6.3.9600